# How to access variable jQuery.fn.init objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I have a function that is `addInputToForm(inputConfig)`

in the function there is a `$el`

In short the function creates `label` and `input element` for `$el`

The new `$el` is a hyperlink field and I do not need the label portion of the `$el`

Using Chrome Developer tools and console I can type out

```
 $el   //Hit return and the result is
 jQuery.fn.init[a#Label Text]  // with triangle to expand
    + 0: a#Label Text  // then an object array displays
       accessKey:
       ...
       innerhtml: "Label Text"
       outerhtml: "Label Text"
```

My question is how do I access these values because I need to change the Text to `""` to be blank.

Comment: `$el[0].innerHTML` or `$el.text("")` or, probably, `$el.find("label").remove()`.  Or change `addInputToForm` so that doesn't create the label (or has an option to determine whether to create it) See here for more info: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: freedomn-m there was more code that performed and append with ```if else``` statement.  I was able to add the correct code and added ```el.css({ marginLeft : "10px", marginRight : "10px" });``` so each link was not right on top of each other.  Please repost you comment as answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see something like

```
jQuery.fn.init[...
```

in the browser console, it means you're looking at a jquery object / collection and so you can apply jquery methods to that object.

For example, to clear the text of a label within an outer element:

```
$el.find("label").text("");
```

For a simple demonstration of the console output, view the result of the below in the browser console (not the snippet console doesn't out the same):

```js
var d = $("#d")
console.log(d)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='d'>div 1</div>
```